# Const definition conflict in Laravel using React and styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, styled-components

I dont know how to use styled-components combined with React in Laravel.
When I try to define the styles, its name is in conflict with the import form the React component that I want to style:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
require('./BlogBody.css')
import BlogCard from './BlogCard';
import styled from 'styled-components';

let BlogCard =  styled.div`
                    width: 413px;
                    height: 380px;
                    z-index: 10;
                    background: linear-gradient(180deg, ${props => props.color.COLOR1} 0%, ${props => props.color.COLOR2} 100%);
                    border-radius: 30px;
                    `;


class BlogBody extends Component {

    


    render() {

        let colorsArray = {
            PURPLE: {
                COLOR1 : "#CC4DA1",
                COLOR2 : "#8C13B8"
            },
            RED: {
                COLOR1 : "#C9522C",
                COLOR2 : "#8B0B0B"
            },
            BLUE: {
                COLOR1 : "#2598EC",
                COLOR2 : "#133FB8"
            },
            GREEN: {
                COLOR1 : "#1BC618",
                COLOR2 : "#7C992B"
            }   
        };

        function colorCalculator(index) {

            let colorIndex = (index+1)%4
             switch (colorIndex) {
                 case 1:    return colorsArray.PURPLE;
                 case 2:    return colorsArray.RED;
                 case 3:    return colorsArray.BLUE;
                 default:   return colorsArray.GREEN;
             }
        }

        let articlesObject = JSON.parse(this.props.articles);

        return (

            <div className="blogBody">
                { articlesObject.map((article, index) => (
                                
                                <BlogCard
                                    key = {index}
                                    title = {article.title}
                                    slug = { article.slug }
                                    // text =  {article.body}
                                    createdAt = { article.created_at }
                                    color = { colorCalculator(index) }
                                /> 
                        )
                )}
            </div>
        
        );
    }
}

export default BlogBody;
```

This code throws:

```
BlogCard.js: Identifier 'BlogCard' has already been declared (16:6)
```

This is because the component and the styles both must have the same constant name.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are importing `BlogCard` on line 3, and are also creating a styled component called `BlogCard`. Just change the name of either of those and it will fix the error

I'm not sure why you need both, but if the goal is to restyle the imported `BlogCard` then change your style component to - `const StyledBlogCard = styled(BlogCard)...`

Comment: I know it. Is mandatory to use the library, that the styles have the same name that the component they're styling and also you have to import the component to use it. The issue here is that I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: That's fine, you can use the BlogCard, you can just change the name, essentially give it an alias when importing it...   `import MyBlogCard from './BlogCard'`

Comment: Don't get hung up on the names, you can call the default import and styled component anything you want, they just have to be different.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not possible in laravel. You have to import each component explicitly

Comment: Have you tried babel-plugin-styled-components?